# Synchronisation of custom widgets in Vaadin 7.1 (global 'tick' event launcher)

Tags: java, widget, customization, vaadin, vaadin7

I have made a custom Vaadin 7.1 widget which displays a timer. This timer gets an initial timing from the server (using a connector) but afterwards ticks further on itself using a separate ticking thread. When using multiple ones next to each other, including ones which run another logic (countdown, etc) they visibly get desynchronized and don't tick together.

A possible solution is to simply have the widget expect a method call (e.g. expect an event to be triggered) from a single separate thread in the code using the widget. Is there something like that offered by the Vaadin framework or what would be the recommended way to do this according to the Framework's standards?